# Processing an array of git commands inside bash script

Tags: bash, git

Good day to all:

I am writing a bash script to pull the data from git repos. I have an array to store the repository names:

```
declare -a arr=(
https://"$USER"@stash/repo1.git
https://"$USER"@stash/rep2.git
)
```

I process it as follows:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    git clone "$i"
    ......
    git install
done
```

This works. Now I want to be able to optionally specify a git branch:

```
declare -a arr=(
    -b branch1 --single-branch https://"$USER"@stash/repo1.git
    https://"$USER"@stash/rep2.git
)
```

The array processing script fails with multiple ugly errors:
- switch `b' requires a value
- not valid identifier, etc

What is the right and simple approach to make it work?

Comment: Show us what you tried, show us what went wrong. Tell us what you want it to do.

Comment: In the second array, the first element is just `-b`, the second element is `branch1`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c.f. `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`. Just because those args are on one line doesn't make them one element. :)

You are trying to do two things with one array.

Try this -

```
declare -a arr=(
   "https://$USER@stash/repo1.git#branch1"
   "https://$USER@stash/rep2.git"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do  IFS='#' read url branch <<< "$i"
    if [[ -n "$branch" ]]
    then git clone -b "$branch" --single-branch "$url"
    else git clone "$url"
    :    ......
    git install
done
```

Warning - no chance to test this. *Caveat Scriptor* - and of course this means `#` can't be in your `url` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work if you remove quotes around

```
git clone "$i"
```

So it would look like this:

```
git clone $i
```

I think that with quotes shell should treat all your line as one single argument instead of many:

```
git clone "-b branch1 --single-branch https://"$USER"@stash/repo1.git"
```

This looks wrong.

EDIT:
@CharlesDuffy pointed to another problem I missed: you should also have quotes around the entire line in the array definition (but this won't work if you really need internal quotes around `$USER`, see example below):

```
declare -a arr=(
    "-b branch1 --single-branch https://$USER@stash/repo1.git"
    https://"$USER"@stash/rep2.git
)
```

I checked this on my local machine, and it seems to work.

```
$ ls
one/  test.sh*

$ ( cd one/ ; git branch )
* another_branch
  master

$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
"-b another_branch --single-branch one two"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        git clone $i
done

$ ls
one/  test.sh*

$ ./test.sh
Cloning into 'two'...
done.

$ ls
one/  test.sh*  two/

$ ( cd two/ ; git branch )
* another_branch

$
```

EDIT2:
This will only work if you can safely omit internal quotes around `$USER`. If you need them you should use eval inside the for loop and also quote the internal quotes in array declaration.

```
$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash

USER="username containing spaces"   # just for example!

git () {
        echo "$5"
}

declare -a arr=(
"-b branch1 --single-branch https://\"$USER\"@stash/repo1.git"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        printf "without eval:\t"
        git clone $i
        printf "with eval:\t"
        eval "git clone $i"
done


$ ./test.sh
without eval:   https://"username
with eval:      https://username containing spaces@stash/repo1.git
```

This is yet another mistake that @CharlesDuffy found in my answer. Thanks Charles, I learn a lot from digging deeper into the problems you pointed!

Comment: Even if you make it `git clone $i`, the first value in the second array is just `-b`, not `-b branch1 --single-branch https://"$USER"@stash/repo1.git`. So the proposed change is breaking with best practice (writing code that relies on string-splitting is responsible for more entries in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) than any other single practice), and doesn't actually fix the OP's issue without *additional* changes not [currently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53942630/2) given in the answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 
True, I missed that author also don't have quotes around array elements. I will add it to my answer.

Word splitting causes a lot of problems, because it is often used unintentionally and incorrectly.
Here I used this particular feature intentionally and knowing what I am doing.

Comment: Quoted internal quotes aren't going to be treated as syntax unless you use `eval` -- as this code presently is implemented, they're going to be passed to `git` as literal data, as unquoted expansions only perform string-splitting and glob expansion, and don't perform quote removal. `for i in "${arr[@]}"; do eval "git clone $i"; done` could work, though. (The unquoted expansion would be safe with the specific data given, but it's not hard to come up with an example where using unquoted expansions to generate an argument list for `eval` breaks things).

Comment: Thanks, Charles! I added it to the answer.